# JSNI call a Java method with a Long param

Tags: gwt, jsni

I need to call a Java method from Javascript. So I defined  the method:

```
private native void registerMethod() /*-{
    var self = this;
    $wnd.test = function(longParam) {
        self.@mypackage.HomeView::test(Ljava/lang/Long;)(longParam);
    };
}-*/;
```

The Java method:

```
private void test(Long longParam) {
    GWT.log("Call to test with longParam =  " + longParam);
}
```

The JS call:

```
public static native void paypalClose() /*-{
    $wnd.alert(top.test);
    top.test(10);
    top.dgFlow.closeFlow();
    top.close();
}-*/;
```

The alert shows the Javascript function definition. If I call `top.test()`, it works but no param is passed. But if I call `top.test(10)` I get a null alert window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method excepts a `java.lang.Long`, not a `long`, so you have to create an instance of `Long`. You could use `@java.lang.Long::new` or `@java.lang.Long::valueOf`, except you cannot use `long`s either in JSNI: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI#important

Because JavaScript numbers are strictly equivalent to Java `double`s, you should use a `double` or `java.lang.Double` as an argument. Once in the Java world, you can cast the double to a long if you like, but not from/in JSNI.